# They vs all of them

Tags: pronouns

Which one is correct or both?

> 1.They are brilliant student. 
>   2.All of them are brilliant student. 
>   3.My uncle has three sons who work in the same office. 
>   4.My uncle has three sons all of whom work in the same office.

Can I replace they with all of them and who with all of whom.

Comment: In the fourth sentence, there should be a comma after *sons* and it should be *who* not *whom*. You also can't use *both* in your question when you've provided four, rather than two, sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, “they”/“all of them” and “who”/“all of whom” can be used interchangeably. Maybe “all of” emphasizes that every single member of the group is included, in case it wasn’t clear before. (Side note: make sure to pluralize “students”- otherwise all four sentences are perfectly correct.)